# JQuery autocomplete submit on change

Tags: jquery

I would like to make the following autocomplete to submit ONCHANGE when you have choosen a value form the dropdownlist.  I always have to press enter once I have choosen a value to submit it and I would like it to submit automatically once you have choosen a value.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#farmname').autocomplete({source:'autocompletefarmname.php', minLength:1});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using jQueryUI Autocomplete. In that case, look [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for a list of options you can use.

The one you need is `change` or `select`:

```
$('#farmname').autocomplete({
         source:'autocompletefarmname.php',
         minLength:1,
         change: function(){
            //submit the result
         }   
       });
```